# SQL Summing digits of a number

Tags: sql, presto

i'm using presto. I have an ID field which is numeric. I want a column that adds up the digits within the id. So if ID=1234, I want a column that outputs 10 i.e 1+2+3+4.

I could use substring to extract each digit and sum it but is there a function I can use or simpler way?

Comment: maybe use [`slice`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html) to generate an array and then simply sum values in array?

Answer (score 2):

You can combine `regexp_extract_all` from @akuhn's answer with [lambda](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/lambda.html) support recently added to Presto. That way you don't need to `unnest`. The code would be really self explanatory if not the need for `cast` to and from `varchar`:

```
presto> select
    reduce(
        regexp_extract_all(cast(x as varchar), '\d'), -- split into digits array
        0, -- initial reduction element
        (s, x) -> s + cast(x as integer), -- reduction function
        s -> s -- finalization
    ) sum_of_digits
from (values 1234) t(x);

 sum_of_digits
---------------
            10
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question correctly you want to avoid having to hardcode a substring grab for each numeral in the ID, like `substring (ID,1,1) + substring (ID,2,1) + ...substring (ID,n,1)`.  Which is inelegant and only works if all your ID values are the same length anyway.

What you can do instead is use a recursive CTE.  Doing it this way works for ID fields with variable value lengths too.

Disclaimer: This does still technically use `substring`, but it does not do the clumsy hardcode grab

```
WITH recur (ID, place, ID_sum)
AS
(
    SELECT ID, 1 , CAST(substring(CAST(ID as varchar),1,1) as int)
    FROM SO_rbase
UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, place + 1, ID_sum + substring(CAST(ID as varchar),place+1,1)  
    FROM recur
    WHERE len(ID) >= place + 1
)

SELECT ID, max(ID_SUM) as ID_sum
FROM recur
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

First use `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL` to split the string. Then use `CROSS JOIN UNNEST GROUP BY` to group the extracted digits by their number and sum over them.

Here,

```
WITH my_table AS (SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('12345'), ('42'), ('789')) AS a (num))
SELECT 
    num, 
    SUM(CAST(digit AS BIGINT)) 
FROM 
    my_table
CROSS JOIN 
    UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(num,'\d')) AS b (digit) 
GROUP BY 
    num
;
```